# How would I go about port-forwarding on azure microsoft 2012 server [azure]

Tags: windows, azure, networking

I'm being in a tough spot, having created 2 different virtual machines on Azure, with windows server 2012 R2 OS. I'm trying to host a game server for a game, which requires ports 7777 and 27015 opened.

What I did is simple, I went into the panel, set-up endpoints for 7777, 27015, for UDP and TCP, and added exceptions to firewall as well for incoming/outcoming 7777, 27015 TCP and UDP.

canyouseeme.org still apparently can't find my service and shows me the ports are not opened. It shows my remote connection port is opened though. What am I doing wrong?  Is there anything more that I need to know?
[Image showing forwarded ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ac3z.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you opened the ports on your Firewall and on the Endpoints screen you are probably fine to game. The problem is probably with the utility that you're testing with and not the ports themselves.

I logged onto an Azure VM that I know I can remotely connect to, tested an open port that I know is open with that website, and it said it did not find it. Maybe that site is using Ping, which gets stuck in Azure's load balancer. To test connectivity, try using PSPing. This will let you test connections to specific ports. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649